# Android Google Sign In for Leaderboards

Tags: android, android-googleapiclient

I am trying to update score using Google Leaderboards, for using Leaderboards I have to use Google SignIn API, my code is copied from https://developers.google.com and i have followed all the steps, created sha1 using:

```
keytool -exportcert  -alias androiddebugkey  -keystore <path-to-debug-keystore> -list -v
```

and put the APP ID in manifest file using:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

but still unable to Sign In, it's been a month I am trying different approaches, but unable to pin point the exact problem, that's why I need your help.

[image]

Comment: You have to generate signed apk file and install it on your device.

Comment: done it...! then this error came, otherwise nothing was happening.

Comment: i have made .jks file with alias- androiddebugkey and password- android , is it ok to use credentials from keytool -exportcert  -alias androiddebugkey  -keystore <path-to-debug-keystore> -list -v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create client id in google developer console with sha1 key and the package name of ur project..

Check this tutorial it will help you.. :)

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

Comment: you have shared a very good tutorial, and i am feeling that at the end of this tutorial i would be able to sign in, but, as this Tutorial is for Eclipse and i am Working on Android Studio, i am stuck on 4th Step: Creating New Project. to be precise i am stuck on 4.2: use Google Play Services project as a library. Can you please specify how to import project as Library in Android Studio. thanks btw for this tutorial.

Comment: In Android studio, start the sdk manager and in Extras u ll find Google play services. Select that and instal that package.. Now goto ur project structure (press ctrl+Alt+Shift+S) , select ur app under modules (in left) then click on dependencies (in right top). Then click on plus symbol on the right and select library dependency. You will get a list of libraries , there select play-services and click ok.

Comment: but this whole code does not have my client ID, how does it link my app on Google APIs console ? and its not working, when i Click SignIn, it asks for permissions, but when i call mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() it returns 'false'

Comment: You have to create a new project in developer console as given in step 1 and 2. In that project u have to add ur project package name and sha1 key.. That is how it will link your app to it.. And u shud add these permissions in ur manifest - <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />